# getting UnimplementedError: Cast string to float is not supported

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I'm trying to implement LSTM network,
when I run run the model.fit I'm getting the following error

```
UnimplementedError:  Cast string to float is not supported
     [[node Cast_2 (defined at <ipython-input-69-cbab83427895>:3) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_7462]

Function call stack:
train_function
```

The following the code of my network

```
    ## as discussed above, please write the LSTM
    input = keras.layers.Input(shape=(X_train_pad_seq.shape[1],1),dtype=float)
    input_mask = keras.layers.Input(shape=(X_train_mask.shape[1]),dtype=bool)
    # lstm_layer = lstm(input)
    lstm_layer = lstm(inputs=input,mask=input_mask)
    # lstm_layer = lstm(input,mask=input_mask)
    dense1 = keras.layers.Dense(128,activation="relu",kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.he_uniform(seed=45))(lstm_layer)
    model = Model(inputs = [input,input_mask],outputs = dense2)
    model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss = keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy,metrics='accuracy')
    model.summary()
    dense2 = keras.layers.Dense(10,activation="softmax",kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.GlorotUniform(seed=45))(dense1)
model = Model(inputs = [input,input_mask],outputs = dense2)
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss = keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy,metrics='accuracy')
model.summary()
```

Comment: Change `metrics='accuracy'` to `metrics=[ 'accuracy' ]` in `model.compile()` method. The `metrics=` argument requires a `list` of metrics and not a `str`.

Comment: Your error is in some `train_function`, but you are not showing that. You may be passing string data as input to the training process.

Comment: Hi the issue is being resolved, the target data that I'm sending is in strring datatype that's the issue. Thanks for you reply.